# Have xargs use alias instead of binary

Tags: bash, alias, xargs

Bash 4.2 on CentOS 6.5:

In my `~/.bash_profile` I have a bunch of aliases, including:

```
alias grep='grep -n --color=always'
```

so that I can get color highlighting and print line numbers automatically when running `grep`. If I run the following, highlighting works as expected:

```
$ grep -Re 'regex_here' *.py
```

However, when I ran this recently:

```
$ find . -name '*.py' | xargs grep -E 'regex_here'
```

the results were not highlighted and line numbers weren't printed, forcing me to go back and explicitly add `-n --color=always` to the `grep` command.

- Does `xargs` not read aliases in the environment?
- If not, is there a way to make it do that?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979453/how-can-i-use-aliased-commands-with-xargs) has what you want.

Comment: @psimon right, that's essentially saying to do what I already did in my workaround - I had to manually expand my alias in the `xargs` command. What I'm trying to find out is if there's a way that I can directly call my alias from `xargs`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An alias is internal to the shell where it is defined. It is not visible to other processes. The same goes for shell functions. `xargs` is a separate application, which is not a shell, so doesn't have a concept of aliases or functions.

You can make xargs invoke a shell instead of invoking `grep` directly. However just invoking a shell isn't enough, you have to define the alias in that shell as well. If the alias is defined in your `.bashrc`, you can source that file; however this may not work your `.bashrc` performs other tasks that don't make sense in a non-interactive shell.

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; grep -E regex_here "$@"' _
```

Beware of the intricacies of nested quoting when typing the regexp. You can simplify your life by passing the regexp as a parameter to the shell.

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; grep -E "$0" "$@"' regex_here
```

You can perform the alias lookup explicitly. Then `xargs` will see `grep -n --color=always`.

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs "${BASH_ALIASES[grep]}" regex_here
```

In zsh:

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs $aliases[grep] regex_here
```

By the way, note that `find … | xargs …` [breaks on filenames containing spaces (among others)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). You can fix this by changing to null-delimited records:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 "${BASH_ALIASES[grep]}" regex_here
```

or by using `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec "${BASH_ALIASES[grep]}" regex_here {} +
```

Instead of calling `find`, you can do everything entirely inside the shell. The glob pattern `**/` traverses directories recursively. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` to enable this glob pattern first.

```
grep regex_here **/*.py
```

This has a few limitations:

- If a lot of files match (or if they have long paths), the command may fail because it exceeds the maximum command line length.
- In bash ≤4.2 (but not in more recent versions, nor in ksh or zsh), `**/` recurses into symbolic links to directories.

Another approach is to [use process substitution, as suggested by MariusMatutiae](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141560).

```
grep regex_here <(find . -name '*.py')
```

This is useful when `**/` isn't applicable: for complex `find` expressions, or in bash ≤4.2 when you don't want to recurse under symbolic links. Note that this breaks on file names containing spaces; a workaround is to [set `IFS` and disable globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), but it's starting to get a bit complex:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; set -f; grep regex_here <(find . -name '*.py') )
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation of why aliases aren't visible to other processes

Comment: One may also use process substitution, see my answer.

Answer (score 28):

Use `alias xargs='xargs '`

```
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
(snip)
A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

Comment: Np. It's also useful with `sudo`…

Comment: It works! THAT'S nasty a.k.a. nifty "shit". Did you find it, or did you know it from another source?

Comment: AFAIR no magic, just RTM with `help alias` (source of my quotation above).

Comment: Well, i guess i'm too deeply involved with too many other things. But i'm always glad blunt solutions exist. On Linux that is. Don't use Windows, it's always a waste of time and effort. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please take this as a demonstration of another approach, which I cannot find in the the related  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979453/2037712):

You can write a wrapper function for `xargs` which checks if the first argument is an alias and if so, expand it accordingly.

Here is a code which does exactly that but unfortunately it requires the *Z shell* and hence does not run 1:1 with bash (and frankly, I'm not used to *bash* enough to port it) :

```
xargs () {
        local expandalias
        if [[ $(which $1) =~ "alias" ]]; then
                expandalias=$(builtin alias $1) 
                expandalias="${${(s.'.)expandalias}[2]}"
        else
                expandalias=$1
        fi
        command xargs ${(z)expandalias} "${(z)@[2,-1]}"
}
```

Proof, that it works:

```
zsh% alias grep="grep -n"´                          # include line number of match
zsh% find foo -name "*.p*" | xargs grep -E test
foo/bar.p0:151:#data=test
foo/bar.p1:122:#data=test                           # line numbers included
zsh% unalias grep
zsh% find foo -name "*.p*" | xargs grep -E test
foo/bar.p0:#data=test
foo/bar.p1:#data=test                               # line numbers not included
zsh%
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler, and more elegant solution, is to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
grep -E 'regex_here' <( find . -name '*.py')
```

It does not create a new shell like the pipe does, which means you are still in your original shell where the alias is defined, and the output is exactly what you wish it to be.

Just be careful to leave no space between redirection and parenthesis, otherwise bash will throw an error. To the best of my knowledge, process substitution is supported by Bash, Zsh, Ksh{88,93}, but not by pdksh (I am told that should be a *not yet*).

Comment: I think pdksh development is dead. Mksh is more or less a successor project — [“pretty hard, it turns out (parsing concept is done in tg@’s head)”](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm#clog).

Comment: Process substitution is a good method for complex `find` commands, though you need to beware that it'll break on spaces, and that can't be fixed as easily as `find | xargs` can be (by switching to `-print0` and `-0`, or using `-exec`). When applicable, `**/` is simpler and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

grep will read a set of default options from the environment variable GREP_OPTIONS.  If you will put

```
 export GREP_OPTIONS='--line-number --color=always'
```

in your .bashrc then the variable will be passed on to subshells and you'll get the results you expect.

Comment: But do not put `--line-number` or `--color=always` in `GREP_OPTIONS` unless it's just for one command, this will break a lot of scripts. `--color=auto` is ok to have there, and that's about all. Putting this line in your `.bashrc` will break a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Gilles Setting any aliases or overriding default options for any command for the root account is a bad thing.  Setting these options for a user account is unlikely to cause many problems. I cannot come up with any user scripts that are problematic.

Comment: Just about any script that uses grep in a way that goes beyond testing the presence of an occurrence will break. For example, from `/etc/init.d/cron` on my system: ``value=`egrep "^${var}=" "$ENV_FILE" | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2` ``. Or from `/usr/bin/pdfjam`: ``pdftitl=`printf "%s" "$PDFinfo" | grep -e … | sed -e …` ``. An alias is not a problem since it isn't seen in scripts.

Comment: @Gilles I'm aware of many scripts like this.  The ones I can't get around are generally run only by root (like /etc/init.d/cron).  Personally, I don't have *any* aliases defined on my user accounts nor do I set options in a rc file or via environment variables to override the default behavior of commands.  I prefer predictability over convenience.

Comment: Aliases don't break predictability since they aren't seen by scripts. Setting `GREP_OPTIONS` breaks predictability very badly, except for a few options like `--color=auto` (which is what it was designed for).

Comment: When you have accounts on some 800+ systems, not all of which share common file systems, keeping a consistent set of aliases is something I don't want to spend time doing.  My fingers know how to type `ls -aCF` automatically without me having to think about it - no need for an alias.