# process substitution for opening a list of files with an application

Tags: bash, alias, xargs, process-substitution, feh

I wish to use process substitution to direct a list of files (produced, for example, by `ls` or `find`) to a particular application for opening/viewing. While piping such a list to `xargs` is suitable for a script or binary, this action fails if the object of `xargs` is a shell alias, as noted in [other questions on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141367/14960). [The particular application I have in mind is `feh`]

Given this limitation of `xargs` vis-a-vis bash aliases, I am instead attempting to use process substitution in the form `[script/binary/alias] <(find . -iname '*')`. This construction gives the desired effect if the list of files is directed to certain shell commands such as `cat` (or `less`, if an input redirection, `<`, is prepended to the process substitution statement); however, it notably fails if the input (a list of paths to files) is instead directed to an application (e.g., `feh`, `gimp`) for opening/viewing. The error accompanying this failure, in the particular case that `feh` is the recipient of the process substitution statement, is "`feh: No loadable images specified.`" Prepending an input redirection operator to the process substitution statement does not alleviate the problem (unlike the case for other commands, e.g., `less`).

Thus, my question concerns whether process substitution can be employed for the stated purpose (that is, opening a list of files), and if so, what the appropriate syntax might be. The specific requirement for compatibility with bash aliases (specified in `~/.bash_aliases` or a similar configuration file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command accepts multiple files as arguments (rather than as the contents read through the pipe), simple command substitution should work:

```
[script/binary/alias] $(find .)
```

Alternatively, if the command only accepts one file at a time, a for loop should do the trick:

```
for file in $(find .); do [script/binary/alias] "$file"; done
```

In both cases filenames containing spaces, tabs, newline, wildcard characters, will cause problems; a while/read loop handles this:

```
find . | while IFS= read -r file; do [script/binary/alias] "$file"; done
```

Filenames containing newlines will still cause problems; `find`'s 0-delimited output will address those (here assuming `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`):

```
find . -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do [script/binary/alias] "$file"; done
```

In all these examples, `find . -type f` might be more appropriate if you only want to process regular files.

Comment: Thank you. Command substitution appears to be precisely what I wanted.

Comment: The problem is not only with spaces, it's with all the characters in `$IFS` and wildcard characters. That `while read` loop still have some problems with spaces (trailing ones) and now also with backslash characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want aliases to be expanded after `xargs`, you can do:

```
alias xargs='xargs '
```

However note that only the first word after `xargs` is subject to alias expansion and that can have unexpected effects if you have aliases for standard commands.

```
$ alias xargs='xargs ' a='echo test'
$ set -x
$ echo x | xargs a
+ echo x
+ xargs echo test
test x
$ echo x | xargs -r a
+ echo x
+ xargs -r a
xargs: a: No such file or directory
```

You may want to call your alias something else and use a more sensible default behaviour for `xargs`. For instance with GNU `xargs`:

```
alias axargs='xargs -r -d "\n" '
```

Now, process substitution expands to one argument: the name of a file which for `<(...)` contains the output of the command (as a live stream).

With the output of `find`, that's only useful for commands that accept as argument a filename expected to contain a newline delimited list of files.

`feh` is one of them:

```
feh -f <(find . -mtime -1 -type f -name '*.jpg')
```

That only works if filenames don't contain newline characters.

The GNU implementation of `xargs` has a `-a` option to take the list of arguments from a file and combined with `-0` and the `-print0` (or `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`) option to `find` allows to pass a list of file names reliably:

```
xargs -r0a <(find ... -print0) feh....
```

That's not helping for your alias problem though.

Now, if you want to pass the output of a command as argument(s) to another command, that's where you'd use *command* substitution as opposed to *process* substitution. Beware of a few caveats though.

```
cmdA "$(cmdB)"
```

passes the output of `cmdB`, without the trailing newline characters as one argument to `cmdA`. For instance, if you have three regular files (here with unusual though perfectly valid names): `* * /etc/passwd .jpg`, `foo.txt` and `<nl><nl>` (where `<nl>` means a newline character), the output of `find . -type f` (`cmdB`) will be `./* * /etc/passwd .jpg<nl>./foo.txt<nl>./<nl><nl><nl>`, so `cmdA` will receive one argument `./* * /etc/passwd .jpg<nl>./foo.txt<nl>./`.

That's probably not what you want. You'd want `cmdA` to receive each file name as separate arguments: `./* * /etc/passwd`, `./foo.txt` and `./<nl><nl>`.

So, basically, you'd need to split the output of `find` into the individual filenames. POSIX shells have an operator for that, the *split+glob* operator which is implicitly invoked when you leave a *command substitution* (or parameter expansion or arithmetic expansion) unquoted.

```
cmdA $(cmdB)
```

will split the output of `cmdB` (without the trailing newline characters) on `$IFS` characters (by default space, tab and newline), and then each word will be subject to globbing.

In our example above, that's not what we want. That would split `./* * /etc/passwd .jpg` into `./*`, `*`, `/etc/passwd` and `.jpg` and those `./*` and `*` would be globbed into the list of files in the current directory.

What we want is to split on newline characters and not do the globbing part. That's done with:

```
IFS='
' # newline only
set -f
cmdA $(cmdB)
```

That still doesn't work for filenames containing newline characters. The output of `find` is generally not post-processable unless you use `-print0` or you can guarantee there will not be file names with newline characters.

Now, only `zsh` allows splitting on `\0` characters:

```
cmdA ${(0)"$(cmdB)"}
```

would split `"$(cmdB)"` on sequences of NUL characters. Or:

```
IFS=$'\0'  # no need for set -f in zsh
cmdA $(cmdB)
```

Another problem with command substitution approaches is that if `cmdB` fails and/or doesn't output anything, `cmdA` will still be run (without argument). It can be avoided with this syntax (still with `zsh`):

```
cmdA ${$(find...):?no file}
```

But if you're using `zsh`, you generally don't need to go down all that trouble anyway since `zsh` supports most of `find`'s functionality internally. For instance, you'd use:

```
myalias ./**/*.jpg(.m-1)
```

To display the `jpg` files last modified within the last 24 hours.